# ¿Cómo crear un documento por cada objeto nuevo JAVA?

Tags: java, archivo, filewriter

¿Cómo puedo crear un nuevo documento a partir de cada objeto nuevo que voy creando en el sistema? Ya que en la version actual se me reescribe el documento que creo por cada objeto creado.

```
    public void writeXML(){
        
        try{
        String ruta = "/home/alumno/DAWprogramacion/Tema 5/CutreCloud/Generador de XML/UsuarioXML.xml";

        File file = new File(ruta);

        if (!file.exists()) {
            file.createNewFile();
        }

        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file);
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
        bw.write(generateXML());
        bw.close();            

        }catch(Exception error){
            error.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Simplemente modifica la ruta cada vez añadiéndole algo diferente, por ejemplo un valor incremental, el timestamp, hora-minuto-segundo... depende de cómo necesites identificarlos en realidad, cualquier cosa que sea "única" serviría

Comment: Si, muchas gracias!